# Rijksmuseum vs Louvre vs Uffizi Gallery

Tags: museums, the-louvre

How would you describe in laymen terms to somebody what the differences is between the Rijksmuseum vs Louvre vs Uffizi Gallery?
How would you classify the type of content inside the museum?

Comment: Unless you are crazy about art, (mostly paintings) do not bother with the Louvre. I have not been in the Uffizi but Rijksmuseum is as much as I can take in one visit, that being said, I mostly go in for a few hours only. (Used to do the lace and silver collection, but those are now mixed in between the paintings.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uffizi Gallery is an art gallery, mostly focused on italian art and with a special focus on Renaissance. I can't find the number of objects in the exposition, but it's probably the smallest of the three.

The Rijksmuseum is **both** an art, a craft and an history museum, meaning that its display of about 8000 objects include both works of arts (paintings, sculptures) and objects of historical importance. And it's a slightly more geared toward Dutch art and history, obviously.

Finally, the Louvre is a huge art, craft and history museum (I mean, really huge: it's the largest museum in the world) with nearly 400.000 objects on display from all the world and all the eras.

Having to explain them any further, or having to suggest them in some way, I'd say that if you plan to see only one museum in your life among those three, you either are really 100% only interested only in italian stuff and thus you visit the Uffizi, or you go a couple days to the Louvre.

Comment: The Louvre always was organized by era; the Egyptian section etc. If you only visit one day, it makes sense to visit different sections, to see some top pieces (like Moma Lisa, Rosetta stone, Toutanchamon etc.)

Comment: If you are only going to one museum in your life, do NOT go to the Louvre, much to big and only suitable for museum lovers. Select one of the smaller museums, better one that is smaller than all three in the question, you might like it and go to an other for more.

Answer (score 0):

I've only been to the Louvre.

The Louvre is BIG; plan at least a couple of days to see everything or plan your visit to only see specific halls.

The Louvre has a lot of diverse exhibitions, Antiquities ( Egyptian , Roman, Greece), a "new-ish" Muslim art section, decorative arts...

There are sculpture halls and painting halls, from many eras and tons of other stuff all over the place.

As far as I can see, the Rijksmuseum and the Uffizi are smaller and more focused on paintings.

I suggest looking at their individual web sites to find out more about them.

http://www.uffizi.org/

https://www.rijksmuseum.nl/en

http://www.louvre.fr/en

Comment: Rijksmuseum has a very good selection of craft and historical items. The current way of displaying does not have them in separate parts anymore but they are still there.